# Using SED or other unix command to fix a date format?

Tags: unix, sed

I have a large file with date formats such as 2014-3-16

Year-Month-Day with a basic regex pattern of [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}

Some entries are in the incorrect format of Month/Day/Year Hour:Minute:Second AM(or PM)

basic regex pattern of [0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]M

I tried to fix these dates using python and csv reader but csv reader introduced all sorts of fun errors like changing quotes in other fields and adding ^M at the end of every line. So I'm trying to learn how to use SED which I think will have the answer. Any help?

Comment: You will get more help if you provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/). The `^M`'s come from EOL (end-of-line) confusion, see [the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) for the details. (I am not the down-voter)

Comment: 27   8       2016    CAT     THIS IS FAKE DATA    What's up    La da da da da   2011    2      show    Last Day    11/12/2014 8:00:00 PM   11/14/2014 3:54:00 AM   2910364        University of Texas    This is more fake data  19.252452452

Comment: If you see here, there's 2 wrongly formatted data.

Comment: Add this information to your question by using the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38397717/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
sed -i -e 's/\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{2,4\}\)\([ :0-9]*[AP]\{1\}M\)/\3-\1-\2/g' file.txt
```

Basically there are three of these patterns:

```
\(\[0-9]\{1,2\}\)\/
```

Which means that it will find one or two [0-9] followed by a /

Then finally a

```
\([ :0-9]*[AP]\{1\}M\)
```

Which finds spaces, colons, and 0-9s that are after the first three patterns, but before the AM or PM. It lumps everything after the third pattern above through the M as one pattern.

The final part:

```
\3-\1-\2
```

Means that it substitutes everything between the 's/... and the first / that is not escaped, with the third pattern, first pattern, and second pattern mentioned. Leaving you with a Year, Month, Date formatting.

Comment: Might be your version of sed is different than the ones I'm using.  You could try to do:

sed 's...[insert your substitutions]...g' file1.txt > file2.txt and see if that does what you want.  If you do man page sed it also might give you a clue as to what the problem is.  It could be you need to escape the dashes in the substitute command, so instead of \3-\1-\2 you'd do \3\-\1\-\2 or something like that.

Comment: switching the order of the -i and -e fixed it! thanks!!

Comment: Great! I updated the answer to reflect what helped you.

Comment: shouldn't the third `\(\[0-9]\{1,2\}\)\/` be `\(\[0-9]\{2,4\}\)\/` or just `\(\[0-9]\{4\}\)\/` to handle 4 digit year?

Comment: Yeah, good catch. Either that or it could be \(20[0-9]\{2\}\)\/ if all of them were formatted for YYYY.

Comment: also, use the `-r` option if available to reduce backslashes... for ex: `sed -r 's/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})([ :0-9]*[AP]{1}M)/\3-\1-\2/g'`

Comment: I was just gonna mention you should edit to catch all 4 digits of year. It might snag someone googling this who doesn't know reg ex at all.